# How to create a drop down that takes input from a text field and show the position on text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating a drop down that takes input like a normal text field and show the position of the text. For this I have created a drop down and a text field and hide the drop down under text field. Now I want to write a Jquery that will take input from the text field and matches it with drop down and if there is a match then show the option from the drop down. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, yes that sounds possible. How do we do it? Not entirely sure. Have you tried something thus far? If yes, please post some code :)

Comment: have you tried anything? are you trying to do a search box like the one we have in firefox? or something like this https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ if so dont reinvent the wheel use jquery ui

Comment: Although I didn't get answer for how to get input in drop down with a text box but I managed to do almost same using a text box with a list populated using AJAX.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with autocomplete Drop-down. Refer this link:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ca3292/autocomplete-dropdown-using-jquery-with-C-Sharp/

Answer (score 0):

Check this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/djv85aLs/)

Js:

```
var options=["First","Second"];
$("#data").on('keyup',function(){
    var v = $(this).val();
    $("#options").html("");
    $.each(options,function(index){
        if(options[index].indexOf(v) > -1){
            $("#options").append("<li>"+options[index]+"</li>");
        }
    })
})
```

**There are better and more efficient ways to do this you may use this as example to start with.

Answer (score 0):

This is your:

HTML

```
Textbox: <input type="text" /><br />
Text and position: <span></span>
<select style="display: none;">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="vw">VW</option>
    <option value="audi" selected>Audi</option>
</select>
```

JQUERY

```
$("input").on('change keyup paste', function(){
    var theInput = this;
    $.each($("select option"), function(index, option){
        if ($(option).val().toLowerCase().trim() == 
            $(theInput).val().toLowerCase().trim()){
            var textToShow = $(option).val().trim() + " " + Number(index + 1);
            $("span").text(textToShow);
            $("select").val($(theInput).val().toLowerCase().trim());
        } else {
            $("span").text("");
        }
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/L000qqr9/1/

Answer (score 0):

and here is another quick example as well

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LVebbr

```js
var $inputField = $('#inputText'),
    $dropdown = $('.dropdown');

$inputField.on('keyup', function(){
  var _value = $(this).val();
  
      $dropdown.children('li').each(function(){

    ( $(this).html().indexOf(_value) > -1 ) ? $(this).css('opacity', '1') : $(this).css('opacity', '0');
  });
  
});
```

```css
.dropdown li{
 
    opacity:0
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="text" id="inputText" />

<ul class="dropdown">
  <li>op1</li>
  <li>op2</li>
  <li>op3</li>
  <li>op3</li>
</ul>
```